# Applescript: set input path from dictionary

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to automatize iWatermark Pro. Dictionary:

[image]

How is it possible to set Input Path and Output Path?

```
tell application "iWatermark Pro"
    activate
    set Input Path "/Users/"
end tell
```

I keep getting: Syntax Error "A “"” can’t go after this property."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the line:

```
set Input Path "/Users/"
```

to:

```
set Input Path to "/Users/"
```